# Can I use a list workflow to make changes in two different lists in SPD 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, list, column, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I want to know if I can use List workflow rather than the Site Workflow to make changes from one list to another if something has been changed or do I need a site workflow to achieve this?

I also want to know that as there is just one option that the Site Workflow to be started manually. I want to know that will it work automatically? As I cannot see any run logs in the Site Workflows in the SharePoint Site Contents unless I run the flow manually from there? Why's that?

Answer (score 2):

**As a short answer,** Yes, you can use `List Workflow` to update list item in another list based on condition in the first list

---

By using **`Update List Item`** Action below **List Actions**

[image]

You can specify Which list you need to update its related list item as shown below

[image]

After specifying the list, specify the field that you need to update based on the condition  in the blue highlighted section

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
The real question would be like this: 

If we do :
Start workflow when an item has changed
If in List 1 value 1 is not equal to value 2
Set value 1 in List 2 equal to List 1 value 1.

Will this work?
I mean in in two different Lists. Merging data between two different links.

Comment: You are welcome, Yes the above steps will help you to achieve your goal! please don't hesitate to ask if you need any further clarification

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the reply. For some reason I still can't make it work.
The situation is : These are two lists: 1: ITS change Calendar 2: IT Request for change List..
I want when the field named "CAB Advisory" in the IT Request for change List = Proceed. Then update the field in ITS change calendar list field named: Category = proceed.
Now we have to choose List: -------...
Add then Set this field: =--------...
To this value: -----....

Find the List Item:
Field: ------...
Value: -------....

I have tried couple of times, can you please help me by filling the above fields. Thanks